# I use POCO parse JSON. It throws an exception:JSON Exception: Bad character. How to handle Chinese characters?

Tags: c++, json, poco-libraries

```
std::string jsonStr; // has Chinese characters..

Poco::Json::Parser parser;
 try {
   parser.parse(jsonStr);
   ...
 }
 catch (Poco::Exception& exc)
 {
  std::cerr << exc.displayText() << std::endl;
 }
```

Could you show me how to handle the Chinese characters? 
Thank you!

Comment: Are chinese character handled correctly otherwise?  If not, you should check the locale.  In this case next link might be of any help, but it is not poco specific: http://blog.csdn.net/wangxvfeng101/article/details/8086421

Comment: What is the encoding of the Chinese characters? If it is GBK, you need to convert it to UTF-8 first because most if not all JSON parsers assume UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Poco JSON parser is capable of reading UTF8 encoded strings, but it struggles with the Byte Order Mark bytes at the beginning of the file. Try to remove them and then parse the string:

```
std::string jsonStr; // has Chinese characters..

Poco::Json::Parser parser;
try {
    Poco::UTF8::removeBOM(jsonStr);  // modifies the string
    parser.parse(jsonStr);
    ...
} catch (Poco::Exception& exc) {
    std::cerr << exc.displayText() << std::endl;
}
```